# How do I detach a firebase snapshot listener in swift?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I've coded the following listener in the viewWillAppear of my ViewController; and am unable to figure out how to remove it.
While I know about the .remove() property in firebase, I still don't know how to exactly implement it here. I really would appreciate the help.

I also have an important question: The VC I have presented below is part of a horizontal-page-type-scroll view. As such, the paging view container that nests this VC(), and 2 others, is always on the screen. Will detaching the listener in the viewWillDisappear() method still work as intended?

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    let db = Firestore.firestore()

    db.collection("main_collection").document("document_one")
    .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
      guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
        print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
        return
      }
        let property = document.get("field_one")
        self.label.text = property as? String
      guard let data = document.data() else {
        print("Document data was empty.")
        return
      }
      print("Current data: \(data)")
    }


}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Detaching a Firestore observer works the same approach on any supported platform: when you attach a listener you get back a function. Call that function to unregister the observer.

From the documentation on [detaching a listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener):

> ```
> let listener = db.collection("cities").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
>    // ...
> }
>
> // ...
>
> // Stop listening to changes
> listener.remove()
> ```

Comment: Thank for this, but this does not seem to work to turn off the listener for me.

Comment: If you're having trouble removing a listener even when you call `listener.remove()`, post a new question with the [minimal code that we can use to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a listener property
2. Assign the listener in viewWillAppear
3. Remove the listener in viewWillDisappear

```
private var listener: ListenerRegistration?

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
 
    // SET LISTENER
    listener = db.collection("main_collection").document("document_one")
        .addSnapshotListener { documentSnapshot, error in
            guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                return
            }
            let property = document.get("field_one")
            self.label.text = property as? String
            guard let data = document.data() else {
                print("Document data was empty.")
               return
            }
            print("Current data: \(data)")
        }
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    // REMOVE LISTENER
    listener.remove()
}
```